# Remove application's container in ember

Tags: ember.js

I see that the whole ember app is rendered wrapped inside a div like:

```
<div id="ember342" class="ember-view">...</div>
```

is it possible to render outside it? (I'd like to keep all the content inside

```
<header> <main> <footer>
```

tags)

Comment: Why can't you just put those tags inside the div?

Comment: aren't they supposed to be the most external containers? And then things like the sticky footer http://materializecss.com/footer.html don't work inside a wrapping div

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You *can* do this, but there are potential side-effects so I wouldn't recommend it. What you have to do is override the application view so it doesn't create a container tag.

```
// application/view.js
export default Ember.View.extend({
    tagName: ''
});
```

This will remove the outer container for the application view. But because there is no outer container, you cannot reference that view in the DOM properly. So things like `this.$()` will not work for the application view. There may also be other side-effects but I'm not 100% sure.

Also note that if you're using Ember 2.0 or greater, `Ember.View` was removed. You can simply extend from `Ember.Component` instead.